# pyTelegramBotAPI: Реализация кнопок "Следующий", "Предыдущий"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Задача такая, реализовать кнопки навигации путем кнопок "Следующий" и "Предыдущий". Страниц будет 4. Собственно вопрос, как я понял действие после клика просходит по имени кнопки 'Следующий >>' В коде по этому имени просходит действие вывод текста страницы 2. Как вывести на экран 3 и 4 страницы?

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.add(*[types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=name, callback_data=name) for name in ['Следующий >>']])
if call.data == '❓ Как это работает?':
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='* Помощь (1 из 4)* \n' 'Текст справки', parse_mode='Markdown',reply_markup=keyboard)
if call.data == 'Следующий >>':
    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id, text='* Помощь (2 из 4)* \n' 'Текст справки 2', parse_mode='Markdown')
```

[image: Как должно быть]

Answer (score 0):

В `callback_data` посылай `faq_3`, где 3 - следующее меню.

Для кнопки `Предыдущий`, `callback_data` будет `faq_1`.

В инлайн-хандлере можно словить данные колбеки вот таким образом:

`if 'faq_' in call.data:
    text, btn = get_faq(call.data.split('_')[1])
    bot.edit_message(text, user_id, mess_id, reply_markup=btn, parse_mode=...)`

Функция `get_faq` будет возвращать текст указанного номера страницы с faq (для `faq_3` этот номер будет `3`) и инлайн-кнопки с `call_data = 'faq_2'` и `faq_4` с текстом `Предыдущий` и `Следующий` соответственно